# Force model.matrix() in R to use a given set of levels

Tags: r, model.matrix

I need to convert a small number of categorical variables in a survey dataframe to dummy variables. The variables are grouped by type (e.g. food type), and within each type survey respondents ranked their 1st, 2nd and 3rd preferences. The list of choices available for each type is similar but not identical. My problem is that I want to force the superset of category choices to be dummy-coded in every case.

```
set.seed(1)
d<-data.frame(foodtype1rank1=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype1rank2=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype1rank3=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype2rank1=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','tuna'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype2rank2=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','tuna'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype2rank3=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','tuna'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype3rank1=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork','mackerel'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype3rank2=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork','mackerel'),5,replace=T),
              foodtype3rank3=sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork','mackerel'),5,replace=T))
```

To recap, model.matrix() will create dummy variables for any individual variable:

```
model.matrix(~d[,1]-1)
  d[, 1]cabbage d[, 1]noodles d[, 1]pork d[, 1]rice
1             0             0          0          1
2             0             0          0          1
3             1             0          0          0
4             0             0          1          0
5             0             1          0          0
```

Or via sapply() for all variables:

```
sapply(d,function(x) model.matrix(~x-1))
```

Naturally, model.matrix() will only consider the levels that are present in each factor separately. But I want to force the complete set of foodtypes to be included for each type: noodles, rice, cabbage, pork, tuna, mackerel. In this example that would generate 54 dummy variables (3 types x 3 ranks x 6 categories). I assume I would pass the complete set explicitly to model.matrix() in some way, but can't see how.

Finally, I know R models automatically dummy-code factors internally but I still need to do it, including for exporting outside R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is by explicitly specifying the levels to each factor:

```
d$foodtype1rank1=factor(sample(c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork'), 5, replace=T), 
                        levels=c('noodles','rice','cabbage','pork','mackerel'))
```

When you know the data this is always good practice.